# Can anyone identify this 6 pin SMD integrated circuit, or what it does?

Tags: identification

Can anyone please identify this 6 pin SMD integrated circuit or what it does? I could not find it by the code written on it. Can anyone find a datasheet for it?

[image]

Comment: Could be the UMN10N Switching Diode base don the fact that the wiring seems to be different on each chip. Maybe you can check with a meter? Or maybe the IMN10T108.

Comment: Measure the package width. 2mm = SOT-363 = UMN10. 2.9mm = SOT-457 = IMN10.

Comment: *This question should include more details and clarify the problem.* - you haven't mentioned what the product is or where it's used.